# how to remove a object in a python list

Tags: python

I create a class named `point` as following:

```
class point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
```

and create a list of `point` instances:

```
p1 = point()
p1.x = 1
p1.y = 1
p2 = point()
p2.x = 2
p2.y = 2
p_list = []
p_list.append(p1)
p_list.append(p2)
```

Now I'd like remove from the list the instance which `x = 1` and `y = 1`, how can I do this?

I try to add a `__cmp__` method for class `point` as following:

```
class point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0    
    def __cmp__(self, p):
        return self.x==p.x and self.y==p.y
```

But the following code does not work

```
r = point()
r.x = 1
r.y = 1
if r in p_list:
    print('correct')
else:
    print('wrong') # it will go here
p_list.remove(r) # it reports 'ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list'
```

Comment: I think this is something to do with `r` not being _identical_ to the item in the list you're trying to remove.

Comment: I think @OrangeFlash81 is right.  Even though p1 and r have the same _values_ for x and y, they aren't the _same object_.

Comment: your `__cmp__` definition doesn't look right to me. It's supposed to return an integer, not a boolean.

Comment: yes, they are not the same object but I'd like the list handle them as the same one as they have the same x and y

Comment: @Kevin I changed the cmp method as following but still not work on python 3.5
    `def __cmp__(self, p):
        if self.x==p.x:
            return self.y-p.y
        else:
            return self.x-p.x`

Comment: one fact I missed: python 3 did not support __cmp__ any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `__cmp__` function is not correct. [`__cmp__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) should return `-1/0/+1` depending on whether the second element is smaller/equal/greater than `self`.  So when your `__cmp__` is called, it returns `True` if the elements are equal, which is then interpreted as `1`, and thus "greater than". And if the elements are non-equal, it returns `False`, i.e. `0`, which is interpreted as "equal").

For two-dimensional points, "greater than" and "smaller than" are not very clearly defined, anyway, so you can just replace your `__cmp__` with [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) using the same implementation. Your `point` class should be:

```
class point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y    

    def __eq__(self, p):
        return self.x==p.x and self.y==p.y
```

Comment: Two notes: first, if you don't also define `__ne__`, then `!=` will still be using identity comparison. Second, it's generally preferred for special methods like `__eq__` to return `NotImplemented` when the other operand isn't a type the method is designed to handle.

Answer (score 0):

When you're checking if `r` is in `p_list` you create a new instance of point, thus that instance of point will not be in the list (it has a different location in memory).

This function works to remove a point where x and y are 1:

```
for idx, p in enumerate(p_list):
    if p.x==1 and p.y==1:
        del p_list[idx]
```